# jasmine - ajax spyon the error request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, unit-testing, jasmine

I am trying to spy the ajax error request and getting the below error. Can you help on this.

**TypeError: e.error is not a function**

## JS code to be tested :

```
function postSettings() {

        $.ajax(
            {
                type: "POST",
                url: EndPoints.Setup,
                data: frm_data,
                success: function (successData) {
                        ///// code is getting covered
                },
                error: function (errorData) {
                        ///// code is not getting covered
                }
            });
    }
```

## Jasmine spec:

```
describe("Call Success path", function () {
            var ajaxSpy;
            beforeEach(function () {
                var MockEndPoints = global.EndPoints = {};
                MockEndPoints.SnmpSetup = "/mock/test/setup";
                ajaxSpy = spyOn($, "ajax").and.callFake(function (e) {
                    e.success(globalFakeData);
                });
            });

            it("Should populate settings", function () {
                Setup.postSettings();
                expect($.ajax).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(2);
            });

        });

        describe("Call Error path", function () {
            var ajaxSpy;
            beforeEach(function () {
                var MockEndPoints = global.EndPoints = {};
                MockEndPoints.SnmpSetup = "/mock/test/setup";
                ajaxSpy = spyOn($, "ajax").and.callFake(function (e) {
                    **e.error; // No error but the path is not covered**
                    **e.error(globalFakeData); // throws the above error**
                });
            });

            it("Should populate settings", function () {
                Setup.postSettings();
                expect($.ajax).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
            }); 
        });
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I'd strongly suggest not trying to spy on / stub `$.ajax` methods directly, and instead use the [jasmine-ajax](https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine-ajax) library.

- In a `beforeEach` do: `jasmine.Ajax.install()`.
- Run your test code, and you can check the ajax request has been made (and intercepted) with `var request = jasmine.Ajax.requests.mostRecent()`. You can then inspect request properties such as `url`, `method`, `data()`.
- To simulate the request succeeding and failing, use `request.respondWith` and pass in `status` codes and `responseText` bodies. A 200 status will simulate success; 4xx or 5xx range will go down the error path. You can then test your `success` and `error` functions do the right thing.